# Using values from two different DataRow.Columns for one DataGridView column

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagrid, datagridview

I need to display a column called Full Name in the my datagridview, but the datasource (datatable) does not have a FullName column.  It only has FirstName and LastName columns.  I'm setting up my DataGridView like this:

```
        Dim column As DataGridViewColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        column.DataPropertyName = "?" //Need FirstName + " " + LastName
        column.Name = "FullName"
        dgv.Columns.Add(column)
```

How can I set the DataPropertyName to use data from both the FirstName and LastName columns in the datatable.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a calculated data column

1. Add a new DataColumn called FullName.
2. Set the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) property to `FirstName + ' ' + LastName`
3. Set the DataPropertyName to FullName

Comment: Thank you.  Expression expects a string...how do you concatenate with a space in between? I tried "FirstName + ' ' + LastName", but that doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: Actually nevermind,  "FirstName + '  ' + LastName" does work.  I had forgotten to add the new column to the datatable.  Thanks again, just what I needed.

Comment: @Prabhu. Sorry I put the double quotes there. I updated the answer in case someone else runs across it.